# Repeat JUnit Tests Passes with Failed Asserts

Tags: spring, testing, junit

This test passes even if AssertErrors are thrown:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MatrixTests 
{    
    @Test
    @Repeat(10)
    public void testMulti() 
    {
         // there are AssertErrors thrown here
    }        
}
```

How do I get the test to fail if one of the iterations fails?

Comment: What class is `@Repeat`?

Comment: Show us the assertions.